# Reading MIDI file (C): 0x00 appearing after the end of a var-length value

Tags: c, hex, midi, binaryfiles, file-format

I'm trying to write some functions to read in a MIDI file. I've been referring to a number of sites that give the specification, but mostly this one: http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227205754/http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html))

I have been testing it on a MIDI file for the Super Mario Bros theme that I downloaded, and I'm getting some unexpected data. It may be that the file is wrongly formatted, but I think it's more likely that I'm doing something wrong. Here is the data (from a hex editor) that I'm having trouble with, and what I *think* I know about it:

```
4D 54 72 6B 00 00 00 19 00 FF 51 03 05 7B 71 00 FF 58 
|---------| |---------| || || || |------| || ||
    MTrk    Chunk size  || || ||  Tempo   || ||
             (25 bytes) || || ||(ms per   || ||
                        \/ || ||1/4 note) || ||
                VLen value || ||          \/ ||
          (Event at time 0)|| ||  VLen value ||
                           \/ || (event at   ||
                 Beginning of ||  time 113)  ||
                 meta-event   ||             ||
                              \/             \/
                 Meta-event type:           ????
                      set tempo
```

As you can see, if everything before the `0x00` is correct, then what is it doing there? The VLen value before has a binary value of `01110001` and so isn't expecting another part of the VLen value, and therefore, AFAIK, *should* be an event type. However there is no event type associated with `0x0`. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem: meta-event codes (in my case `0x51`) are proceeded by a chunk size just like normal events. The reason I thought otherwise is because, for the set tempo meta-event, the tempo data size is always 3. Therefore `51 03 05 7B 71` is actually the set tempo event code (`51`), the size of the tempo data (`03`) then the actual tempo (`05 7B 71`), and then the `00` is just another variable-length value telling me that the next event is at time 0.

I hope this helps someone. I also found a better piece of documentation for the MIDI format which made this clearer: http://www.omega-art.com/midi/mfiles.html ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20121227014815/http://www.omega-art.com/midi/mfiles.html))